# How can I hide flights in Google Flights that contain a stopover requiring a change of airport?

Tags: google-flights

How can I hide flight in Google Flights that contain a stopover requiring a change of airport?

Example (screenshot taken in 2020, hence the Sat 29 Aug.):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Google Flights does not have any filter allowing users to hide flights contain a stopover requiring a change of airport.